# Start parallax when element is in viewport

Tags: javascript

I working on a site with parallax effect on multiple elements (text, images etc.). I need to start parallax effect when element is at the bottom in viewport.

In this case element is 3000px from the top of the page and I want to reset window.pageYOffset to zero (or something like that) when element is in viewport that effect make sense.

This code is working but is not good, when I change separator height, start position of the parallax effect is different. You can try to change separator height in css to 500px and 5000px.

What is better solution for this?

THX

Here is fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/you8c6d7/

```js
function parallax(element, delay) {
  var start = document.querySelector(element).getBoundingClientRect().top;
  var px = window.pageYOffset - (start * 2 + window.innerHeight);
  var elClass = document.querySelector(element);

  elClass.style.transform = 'translateY(' + '-' + px / delay + 'px' + ')';
};

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  parallax('.box', 5);
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 6000px;
  margin 0;
}

.box {
  background: blue;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.separator {
  height: 500px;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="separator"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: you are triggering parallax on scroll i would suggest put a if condition if the element offsetTop is in range to windowYoffset top then start parallax no?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a snippet using the [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API).

I used [the experimental feature "IntersectionObserver.thresholds"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver/thresholds), that is therefore [not supported by IE](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-api_intersectionobserver_thresholds).

Depending on your [target audience](https://caniuse.com/#feat=intersectionobserver), you might need to use a [polyfill](https://github.com/w3c/IntersectionObserver/tree/master/polyfill).

The script observes if the target box intersects with the viewport and transform it according to the ratio of box/viewport. See the comments and JSDoc inside the code for more detail.

```js
/**
 * Creates an IntersectionObserver and starts observing all elements found using the selector.
 *
 * @param {String} selector: Selector used to find all target elements
 * @param {Number[]} threshold: Array of intersection ratios, at which the callback is executed
 * @param {Function} callback: Callback executed for each threshold
 */
function observe(selector, threshold, callback) {
  const elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  const options = {
    rootMargin: '0px',
    threshold: threshold,
  };

  const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);

  for (const element of elements) {
    observer.observe(element);
  }
}

/**
 * Creates a CSS translateY value.
 *
 * @param {Number} ratio: A number between 0 and 1
 * @param {String} total: A valid CSS number and unit (10px, 100%, 30vh, …)
 * @return {String} The CSS translateY value.
 */
function translateY(ratio, total) {
  return `translateY(calc(-${ratio} * ${total})`;
}

/**
 * Callback executed for the box elements
 *
 * @see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API
 *
 * @param {IntersectionObserverEntry[]} entries: Intersection Observer Entries
 * @param {IntersectionObserver} observer: Intersection Observer
 */
function boxParallax(entries, observer) {
  for (const entry of entries) {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      entry.target.style.transform = translateY(entry.intersectionRatio, '20%');
    }
  }
}

/**
 * Create one threshold for each intersection ratio.
 *
 * @return {Number[]}
 */
function createThreshold() {
  const threshold = [];
  for (let i = 0; i <= 1.0; i += 0.01) {
    threshold.push(i);
  }

  return threshold;
}

const threshold = createThreshold();
observe('.box', threshold, boxParallax);
```

```css
body {
  height: 6000px;
  margin 0;
}

.box {
  background: blue;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.separator {
  height: 500px;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="separator"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This looks like it could be done with [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) (IO)

It's not recommended to listen to scroll event and always calculate positions of (multiple) elements, this can lead to a bad performance. With IO you can tell the browser to react to elements getting into view, leaving the view or intersecting with each other without having a poor performance.

Note: You may not notice a poor performance if you only use scroll event listeners to calculate only a few elements, but especially on weaker phones or with more elements you can start to notice this bad performance.

How to use IO:

You would first have to define the options for your IO, if you don't define a root element it uses the whole viewport for checking if there is an intersection.

```
let options = {
  rootMargin: '0px',
  threshold: 1.0
}

let observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);
```

Everytime an element gets into view (with the options specified), a callback function is getting called.

Next step is to define one (or multiple) elements the observer should watch, in your case this would be the `.box` element:

```
let targets = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
targets.forEach(target => {
  observer.observe(target) 
});
```

Final step is then to define the callback function mentioned before:

```
let callback = (entries, observer) => { 
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    // Each entry describes an intersection change for one observed
    // target element:
    //   entry.boundingClientRect
    //   entry.intersectionRatio
    //   entry.intersectionRect
    //   entry.isIntersecting
    //   entry.rootBounds
    //   entry.target
    //   entry.time
  });
};
```

Inside the function you can then change the position.

Note: IO does only trigger when there is a change, so while the image is fully visible you won't get any callbacks, maybe here you would have to use scroll event in the end to do the "moving" of the image. I would suggest adding the scroll event only when the element is in view and removing it when the element is no longer in view. Maybe there is solution for only using IO but I can't think of one right away.

Also check out this [polyfill from w3c](https://github.com/w3c/IntersectionObserver) to support older browsers.